# Force Screen Reader to Read When A Component Is Removed

Tags: javascript, html, angular, accessibility, screen-readers

I need the screen reader to read "All Filters Are Removed" when all the filter items are removed. The tricky part is: when the active filter component is removed, there's no other element for me to set `aria-label` to `All filters are removed`. I was wondering how to force the screen reader to read something in this case?

The HTML Example is here:

```
<div *ngIf="activeFilters.length > 0">
    <div class="active-filters" attr.aria-label="{{'List of active filters'}}">
        <h4 class="active-filters-headline">{{'Active filters'}}</h4>
  
    </div>
</div>
```

When all the filter items are removed, the `active-filters` component will not show up. Because the `activeFilters.length` would be 0. So I am not sure how to put `aria-label` on the element that does not exist.

Here is the typescript code that could potentially introduce the screen reader logic:

```
  ngAfterViewChecked() {
            if (this.interaction && this.interactionDataDelivery) {
                this.interaction = this.interactionDataDelivery = false;
                if (this.activeFilters.length == 0) {
                    //How do I set up the aria-label?
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this in the past by creating an element with `aria-live="assertive"`, using [some CSS trickery](https://www.a11yproject.com/posts/2013-01-11-how-to-hide-content/) to have it hidden except for screen readers, and then setting its `innerHTML`. Something along these lines:

```
const $message = document.createElement('span');
$message.classList.add('visuallyhidden'); // <-- Some method of making sure this element is only seen by screen readers
$message.setAttribute('aria-live', 'assertive');

document.body.appendChild($message);

const speak = function (message) {
    $message.innerHTML = '';
    window.setTimeout(() => {
        $message.innerHTML = message;
    }, 100);
};
```

You may also want to take some measures to ensure people using screen readers can't manually navigate to the alert message element as well, such as by clearing its content after the fact or perhaps by controlling its `aria-hidden` attribute.

Comment: Thank you and it worked! I was wondering when I should remove the `visuallyhidden` class in order to make sure that it is removed after the screen reader announces the aria-label?

Comment: The way I use that class is to prevent an element from being visible on the page, but still allowing it to be seen by a screen reader. So if you were to just remove that class while using it in that way, it would only cause the element to appear on the page. You may instead want to either give it `display: none;` when it's not in use, or apply `aria-hidden="true"`